# Logic Behind "tsclean" function of package "forecast"

Tags: time-series, forecasting

Can anyone please explain the logic behind the functions like "tsclean" & "nnetar"  of the package "forecast" written by Professor Rob J Hyndman.

I can able to use the tsclean & nnetar.

I hope these are used for the outlier treatment in time series.

tsclean is used for outlier treatment, i.e. it removes outliers & it fills the missing values.

Request:
What is the method or logic behind it, please let me know (any reference material)

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: You could start with the help file: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forecast/versions/8.1/topics/tsclean

Comment: Or you could just look at the code.